# Visual Studio debugger not stopping at C++ exception in managed application

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-debugging

I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.

this->LabelProperty-> was 0xFF...FF2F

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Visual Studio stops in C# and highlights a line where LabelProperty doesn't exist and is in a C++ DLL. How do I get Visual Studio to debug this properly as at the moment it's not showing me the source line correctly.

I have "Enable native code debugging" checked on the top level application. Do I need to set this on all the assemblies as well?

Comment: Are you attaching to the process with Native debugger, in addition to the managed one (i.e. is `Native` selected in `Debug` -> `Attach to process` -> `Attach to`)?

Comment: A read access violation is not an exception thrown by C++ code. It is an exception raised by the system when you try to dereference a pointer that contains the address of an invalid location. From your description, it sounds like the problem *is* in the C# code, so the debugger's behavior makes good sense stopping there.

Comment: The exception occurs in a DLL which is a C++ DLL. If I continue it says: unhandled exception at 0x00007FF...08 (app.dll) in app.exe.

Comment: Just checked - read access violation *is* one thrown by C++ code. Just got it to occur with VS 2015 and some sample code.

Comment: When one speaks of an exception being thrown by code, it means that the code has a `throw` statement. That isn't happening here. As I said, a read access violation is raised by the operating system. But, okay, the exception is being raised in response to buggy code in a C++ DLL. So the issue is that your development environment is incorrectly configured. There are about a dozen different possibilities, far too many for me to speculate about. Mixed-mode debugging works fine for me, and has on innumerable versions of Visual Studio. We'd need more info to make this less speculative.

Comment: As I said, I tried a simpler sample. It stops immediately on the line that throws the exception, and it's a mixed mode application (C++ DLL with C# console app). Using the same Visual Studio the bigger application stops on a C# Join line which I think is wrong since the exception mentions a field that doesn't exist in C#. I'm guessing it must be a project setting that's wrong rather than VS being wrongly configured.

Comment: @imekon, Please make sure that it was not related to the VS debugging settings under TOOLS->Options->Debugging like "Use Managed/Native Compatibility Mode" or "Step over properties and Operators(Managed Only)", if still no help, I suggest you provide the main code, so we could repro this issue in our side using the same Environment as yours. But based on the error messages, I think we would think about the code itself: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6decc55h.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396